# Wasawis, I get Bad thoughts all the time

Tags: ibadah

I've been a victim of extremely bad wasawis about Nabi Pak (SAW) & Allah. I'm so sick of it sometimes I want to kill myself I try to control myself alot but they all of a sudden pop up in my head and I start hating myself and want to kill myself.

I did 2 Khatme Quraan this Ramadan but with all the bad Wasawis kept coming in my head what should I do...?

I would kill myself if this doesn't stop... I'm not an evil person; My family even thinks I'm an angelic soul since I do ibadat a lot, but I can't enjoy my Ibadat due to this problem

I don't even have the satisfaction of my ibadat getting accepted by Allah or satisfaction that my prayers would be answered what am I supposed to do?

May Allah Send death upon me and may I rot in Hell & Qabar for the bad things my mind & heart think this could be my only punishment I want to die and rot in hell

Comment: Do not lose hope of Allah's mercy. You say you seek death and hell, do you claim that your sins are so big that it surpasses Allah's mercy? No, seek forgiveness and you will be forgiven. Sorry about your situation.

Comment: What I would suggest stop blaming yourself. It is not your fault. I know in somewhat you think you are an evil person but just love yourself what ever you are and do not *act* wrong. If you have thinking, you have no control over it. Just be cautious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for spiritual healing and/or diagnosis, which this site is ill-suited to providing (see http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/854/22)

Answer (score 7):

[image: In the name of Allah, The Most Beneficent, The most Merciful]

You are not the only one who is victimized by the whispers of shaitan. Even in the time of Prophet [image: (Peace be upon him)] such incidents have been witnessed.

> #### [Sunan Abi Dawood (Kitab Al-Adab)  :: Hadith 5112](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/340)
>
> Narrated Abdullah ibn Abbas:
> A man came to the Prophet [image: (Peace be upon him)] and said: Messenger of Allah! one of us has thoughts of such nature that he would rather be reduced to charcoal than speak about them. He said: Allah is Most Great, Allah is Most Great, Allah is Most Great. Praise be to Allah Who has reduced the guile of the devil to evil prompting. Ibn Qudamah said "reduced his matter" instead of "reduced his guile".
>   Ibn Qudamah said "reduced his matter" instead of "reduced his guile".

But our beloved Prophet [image: (Peace be upon him)] has assured us that unless such kind of evil whispers are ignored and the evil thoughts are not acted upon, Allah [image: Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala] forgives us.

> #### [Sahih al-Bukhari :: Hadith 6664](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/42)
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   The Prophet [image: (Peace be upon him)] said, "Allah forgives my followers those (evil deeds) their souls may whisper or suggest to them as long as they do not act (on it) or speak."
>
> #### [Sahih al-Bukhari :: Hadith 5269](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/68/19)
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   The Prophet [image: (Peace be upon him)] said, "Allah has forgiven my followers the evil thoughts that occur to their minds, as long as such thoughts are not put into action or uttered." And Qatada said, "If someone divorces his wife just in his mind, such an unuttered divorce has no effect.

So, you should constantly seek refuge in Allah from these Wasawis (whispers) just like our Prophet [image: (Peace be upon him)] did.

> #### [Sunan Abi Dawood (Kitab as-Salaah) :: Hadith 1539](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/124)
>
> Narrated Umar ibn al-Khattab:
>   The Prophet [image: (Peace be upon him)] used to seek refuge in Allah from five things; cowardliness, niggardliness, the evils of old age, **evil thoughts**, and punishment in the grave.

It is clear from your question that Shaitaan has victimized you to an extent where you curse yourself and now you are asking hell (na'uzubillah) for yourself. By doing this you are are being unfaithful to yourself and you are just making the shaitaan's work of sending you to hell more easy.

In conclusion,

- **Never Again ask for death due to such failures**

  > #### [Sahih al-Bukhari :: Hadith 6351](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/48)
  >
  > Narrated Anas:
  >   Allah's Messenger [image: (Peace be upon him)] said," None of you should long for death because of a calamity that had befallen him, and if he cannot, but long for death, then he should say, 'O Allah! Let me live as long as life is better for me, and take my life if death is better for me.' "
- **Be faithful to yourself:** Never again ask hell for yourself. Instead seek refuge in Allah from Shaitaan and the Hell.
- **Be faithful to Allah [image: Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala]:** Believe that Allah [image: Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala] is aware that human mind is seldom under self control and is subject to these thoughts. Hence believe that Allah will forgive you.
- **Ignore the whispers:** Ignore them and seek refuge from them.
- **Carry on with your Ibadah:** Rather, offer more prayers than before and Inshaa Allah your head will be cleared from these thoughts.

[image: And Allah is the All-Knower, The Wise]

Answer (score 3):

**The cause:**

> Some of the Sahaabah complained about the waswaas that was bothering
>   them. Some of the companions of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) came to the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) and said to him, ‘We find in
>   ourselves thoughts that are too terrible to speak of.’ He said, ‘Are
>   you really having such thoughts?’ They said, ‘Yes.’ He said, ‘That is
>   a clear sign of faith.’” (Narrated by Muslim).   (Narrated by Muslim,
>   132 from the hadeeth of Abu Hurayrah).

**The solution:**

> Finally we advise you to keep on turning to Allaah in all situations,
>   and to ask Him for help, and to beseech Him, and to ask Him to make
>   you steadfast until death, and to cause you to die doing righteous
>   deeds… And Allaah knows best.

Source: http://islamqa.com/en/ref/25778

**My own thoughts:**

When you ask Allah "How do I get these thoughts out of my head", you should get an answer which helps you realise that the only free will we humans have is our thoughts.  From here you should be able to realise that if you choose not to train your mind with positive thoughts, the negative thoughts will fill in the gaps.  You need to use your free will to manually on a daily bases fill your mind with positive thoughts.  Don't leave the devil any space in your mind to fill your mind with bad thoughts, will your mind with positive thoughts so you have no gaps in your mind for the devil to use.

Comment: +1 for your **"My own thoughts"**, the quoted hadith and a good answer over all.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain brother.

You know at the time of birth of Isa (RA) Satan said that he will keep on his evil deeds till the Doom's day. So he is. Its just satan who is trying to make you feel or think about such hidious things. Don't feel pity. Just pray alot and alot and alot.

Only prayer can take you out of this situation. You completed Quran twice; Masha-Allah. And if your family thinks your an angel soul, then you might be! Every soul is angel unless it turns from Allah.

At a certain age, the human minds keep regreting for what he is doing. The human mind keep thinking that what he actually thinks is true might not be true. I hope you understand! Just pray to Allah to help you and guide you.

When you pray, you read these verses of Surah-Fatiyah: Guide me on the right path, the path of those; on whom you blessed! He will bless you :) Just have a keen faith in him. He is Raheem and Rehman!

Answer (score 0):

Ye your not alone sister I get bad thoughts too I've had them since I become Muslim which is over 2 years now Alhamdulilah I nearly give up islam before because of them there so bad I don't no what to do I just ask for forgiveness Maybe it's a test from Allah (swt) or a calamity I no it's hard just make loads of dua and Allah will help you in Shaa Allah my family are there same they all think I'm a good person n have a nice heart Alhamdulilah I wouldn't wish bad or think bad of anyone these thoughts just come to my mind even without me thinking about them just the satan playing tricks I hope u get through them in Shaa Allah I no it's hard may Allah cure us in Shaa Allah Ameen ya rabb

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaykum brothers and sisters. You know as I read this question and the answers, I am surprises that it isn't only me who has these very same thoughts. Whenever these evil thoughts get into my mind, I say Istighfar and ask Allah's forgiveness. i also send blessings to my beloved Prophet Muhammad pbuh. I praise Allah. these actions help me counteract these evil whispers. I also ask Almighty Allah for help. Truly, without His help I cannot overcome these thoughts. So, whenever you get these thoughts, ask Allah's help and counteract them by praising Allah much and sending blessings to our beloved Prophet Muhammad pbuh. I believe The fact that you get angry with yourself when you have these thoughts signifies that there is good in you. You are a good person. keep remembering Allah. Jazakallahu khairan...

Answer (score -1):

Maleeha,

Dear sister, you are not alone.  I too am a victim of satanic whispers,

I get bad thoughts about Allah (SWT),his Prophets (SAW),his wife,companions etc. The whispering very bad until to the point i was depressed most of the time. And i felt i will go insane if this continues.

Alhamdulillah, I met a local imam few months ago. At one look,he asked me,

"Do you get kufr,shirk thoughts?"

Then I replied "Yes I do".

He explained his experience as he had the same issue 5 to 6 years back. He managed to cure it by drinking holy zam zam water.He advised me to divert my attention and ignore whenever it disturbs.

The only solution is ignore. Alhamdulillah, I got a chance to drink the holy zam zam water and the whisperings reduced to a great extend.

The whisperings will be there until you practice your Deen.

I used to think why am i getting bad thoughts only about my respected and beloved Lord and not any others  other people. I am sure it is satan is behind all this. And my Lord has already forgiven satanic whispers.

I read that many people are struggling with waswas and I shall convince myself that I'm not the only one. This includes many good muslims. It is the handy work of satan. In Sha Allah, you will be cured by the mercy of our Lord. Include me in your prayers sister.

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. Please go through [answer].